# Linux / Folder and /root folder

Tags: linux, centos, root

I searched now a while but couldn't find an answer to this question.

I have a Linux based server (centOs).

In the root folder (/) i have a folder called root (/root).

Now when I sudo cd root/ i stay in the same folder (/).

First I thought that /root is a symlink but symlinks are cian blue and here I have dark blue.

I've read that the /root folder is  the root user folder but I don't get in it.

Can somebody please explain what is going on here?

Comment: `cd` is a builtin shell command, so doing `sudo cd /root` won't work (and you'll get an "command not found" error). You need to use a shell as root to use what's there (`su -` for instance) or do `sudo ls -a /root` if you want to see what's there.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, but i didn't get an error message.

Comment: @OlivierKrull, Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### `/` (Root directory) vs `/root` directory

1. `/` directory called as `Root Directory` sits on the top of the file system hierarchy.

   - That means it is the ultimate parent or grandparent or grand grandparent of any file or directory you can find on your system.
   - It contains all the files necessary for the system to work such as boot files, libraries, packages, essential binaries, system configuration, user files and temporary files.

[image: Linux file system]
<sub>[source](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/06/18/linux-file-system-hierarchy-v2-0/)</sub>

2. Now `/root` is the `Home directory for User named Root`. See at the bottom right in above image.

   - Just like every User has it's own directory with his/her username under `/home`, User `Root` must have also a directory.
   - But Since `Root` user needs to know every tiny detail about system, so his home directory is created under `/` itself by the name `/root`
   - It contains the files and folders you created when you were root user and also the hidden configuration files for some applications or packages you installed.

#### Now when I `sudo cd root/` I stay in the same folder (/)

As pointed by [cylglad](https://superuser.com/users/491839/cylgalad) in the comments,

```
cd is a builtin shell command, so doing sudo cd /root won't work
```

See this :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ cd /root
bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ 
amit@C0deDaedalus:~$ sudo cd /root
[sudo] password for amit: 
sudo: cd: command not found
```

Instead you have to first change to root user, then do a cd to `/root`

```
$ sudo -i
# cd /root
# pwd
```

Feel free to add in more details.

Answer (score 1):

change to the root user and then CD to it

```
$ sudo su
# cd /root
```

as was previously mentioned, cd is a bash built-in and can't be executed using sudo.  if you want to see the permissions on a directory, try

```
$ ls -al
```

then look at the permission column to determine if the user you are logged in with has permissions.

Comment: sudo -s / sudo -i / su / su - , but not "sudo su"

Comment: @TomYan why not sudo su? It is effectively sudo -i.   A root password is not always set and su by itself will not work in those cases.

Comment: for it's silly and unnecessary (and other possible issues)

Answer (score 0):

Your root folder is **/**. Your **/root** is the root's **home** folder. For instance if you create a user called test, then it's home folder is /home/test. For root user, it is simply /root instead of /home/root.

Comment: Yes i already understood this. But when i want to get inside the /root directory i stay in (/).